# First call to AWS_IAM Secured API endpoint is always unauthorized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

Im building a service + client using the following Amazon technologies:

1. Lambda
2. S3
3. API Gateway
4. Cognito
5. Federated Identities

Im using the serverless framework to build and deploy the API.
The client is a angular 1 app hosted in a S3 bucket.

The API endpoint is secured using AWS_IAM, the issue is that the first call to the API from my JS client is unauthorized, every call after that (using the same credentials) are authorized. I can see in my log that

```
var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;
```

is undefined the first time I make the call.

What I hope to achieve is that to retrieve the needed credentials so the first call succeeds.

The code below is what is used to get the credentials from Amazon Cognito and call the API. Im using the generated javascript SDK from AWS API Gateway to sign the request and call the API.

```
        var authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito
            .CognitoIdentityServiceProvider
            .AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
            onSuccess: function (result) {

                var logins = {}
                logins["cognito url" + "/" + "cognito pool id"] = result.idToken.jwtToken
                AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                    IdentityPoolId: "identity pool id",
                    Logins: logins
                });



                AWS
                    .config
                    .credentials
                    .get(function () {

                        var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
                        var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
                        var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

                        var config = {
                            accessKey: accessKeyId,
                            secretKey: secretAccessKey,
                            sessionToken: sessionToken


                        }

                        var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient(config);


                        apigClient
                            .endpointName(params, body, additionalParams)
                            .then(function (result) {

                            deferred.resolve(true)


                            })
                            .catch(function (result) {
                                deferred.resolve(false)

                            });

                    });

            },

            onFailure: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });

        return deferred.promise;

    }
}
```

Comment: I think that aws.config.cred.get((err) that function first param is the error... you should check if there is any error message there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I did not refresh the credentials after retrieval. For further reference the code used is below:

```
       AWS.config.credentials.get(function() {

          AWS.config.credentials.refresh(function(error) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);

              // rejects promise with error message
            } else {

              var accessKeyId = AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId;
              var secretAccessKey = AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey;
              var sessionToken = AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken;

              console.log(accessKeyId);
              console.log(secretAccessKey);
              console.log(sessionToken);

            }
          });

        });
```